# How to get mutableList of mutableList in kotlin?

Tags: arrays, android-studio, google-maps, kotlin, polyline

I am trying to get mutableList of mutableList of LatLng pairs in kotlin. Below is my code.
When the function `onPauseButtonClicked()`is called I get the value in `locationlist` variable which is mutableList of LatLng pairs.But I am not able to add the value to `locationlists` variable which is a `mutableListOf(locationList)` . The value is shown empty. What is wrong with code.

```
 private var locationList = mutableListOf<LatLng>()

 private var locationlists = mutableListOf(locationList)

/**
This is function where locationlists is called
*/

 private fun onPauseButtonClicked(){

        locationlists.add(locationList)

//        Toast.makeText(requireContext() ,"$locationList", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

        val c= locationlists[0]

        Toast.makeText(requireContext() ,"$c", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`add` will add the MutableList to the end of the list. However, when you call `mutableListOf(locationList)` you already put an empty MutableList as the first element. It's easy to verify in the debugger, that your locationlists will have two elements, eventhough you only call `add` once.

Therefore, the correct way would be to initialize locationlists with an empty list of MutableList

```
var locationlists =  mutableListOf<MutableList<LatLng>>()
```

Answer (score 1):

While initializing use

```
private val locationLists = MutableList<MutableList<LatLang>>(0){mutableListOf()}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate , cause are you only adding 1 object , or you are populating in other way ? and get where?

Comment: When I do `locationlists.add(locationList)` the old values some how gets deleted. I am only able to retrieve the newly added value in `locationlists`.

Comment: is your scope of deceleration of parent right ? , because `add()` appends to end

Comment: @user16493824 your question needs a bit more elaborating as @Anshul asked. Can you provide more context on what gets appended/removed from `locationList`? 

Storing a mutable list that will get modified further after insertion in `locationLists` seems the possible source of the issue here. Consider making an immutable copy before inserting into `locationLists` if mutability post-insertion is not needed.

Comment: I have array of `LatLng` pairs as `mutableListOf<LatLng>()`inside my `locationList` variable. I am trying to add  `locationList` to another variable `locationlists` which is now  ` val locationlists = MutableList<MutableList<LatLng>>(0){mutableListOf()}`(array of array). But When I run the code I am only able to retrieve values in `locationlists[size-1]`. Other values gets deleted.

Comment: Are you sure you are not overwriting the variable ?